# How do I prove $(\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \beta)$ in the four-axiom proof-system described herein?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Show that $(\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \beta)$ is a theorem, under the proof-system defined by the four axioms and rule of inference stated below. (Note how this is different from the *usual* three-axiom proof-system - we've replaced $(\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \beta)$ by axioms **(3)** and **(4)**).

So, I tried to use **(1)** and began with $(\alpha \to \beta) \to ((\lnot \beta \to \lnot \alpha) \to (\alpha \to \beta))$, but couldn't get anywhere from here (got too messy). Could someone please help me get to the solution? Proving theorems using axioms (below) has always been troublesome for me.

**List of Axioms:**

- $\alpha \to (\beta \to \alpha)$ **(1)**
- $(\alpha \to (\beta \to \gamma)) \to ((\alpha \to \beta) \to (\alpha \to \gamma))$ **(2)**
- $\lnot \alpha \to (\alpha \to \beta)$ **(3)**
- $(\lnot \alpha \to \alpha) \to \alpha$ **(4)**

and Modus-Ponens is the sole rule of inference.

Comment: https://www.umsu.de/trees/#%20(%C2%AC%CE%B2%E2%86%92%C2%AC%CE%B1)%E2%86%92(%CE%B1%E2%86%92%CE%B2)%20

Comment: Can you make use of the Deduction Theorem?

Comment: Which book is this exercise from?

Comment: Isn't from a book, just something I was curious about since I'd read that these 4 axioms constitute a valid axiomatic proof system too.

Comment: Ok, so where did you read that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing about proof systems like this one is that you never actually want to write proofs in them. Instead, you usually make use of meta-theorems (like the deduction theorem) to make your life easier. I'll describe a proof using the deduction theorem, which could then in principle be unwound (following the inductive proof of the deduction theorem) into a real (but much longer!) proof in the system.

So what's the strategy for proving $(\lnot \beta\to \lnot \alpha)\to (\alpha\to \beta)$? We want to assume $(\lnot \beta\to \lnot \alpha)$ and prove $(\alpha\to \beta)$. To prove $(\alpha\to \beta)$, we want to assume $\alpha$ and prove $\beta$. Ok, how can we prove $\beta$ based on our assumptions $(\lnot \beta\to \lnot \alpha)$ and $\alpha$? Well, rule (4) gives us a limited method of proof by contradiction. If we want to prove $\beta$, it suffices to prove $(\lnot \beta\to \beta)$. And to prove $(\lnot \beta\to \beta)$, we want to assume $\lnot \beta$ and prove $\beta$. Now we're in business: from our assumptions $(\lnot \beta\to \lnot \alpha)$ and $\lnot \beta$, we get $\lnot \alpha$. Together with our assumption $\alpha$, we should be able to use the principle of explosion to get $\beta$. This is implemented by rule (3): we have $(\lnot \alpha\to (\alpha\to \beta)$, so applying modus ponens twice, we get $\beta$.

Let's turn this strategy into a proof:

1. $(\lnot\beta\to \lnot \alpha)$ (Assumption)
2. $\alpha$ (Assumption)
3. $\lnot \beta$ (Assumption)
4. $\lnot \alpha$ (MP from 1. and 3.)
5. $\lnot \alpha\to (\alpha\to \beta)$ (3)
6. $\alpha\to \beta$ (MP from 4. and 5.)
7. $\beta$ (MP from 2. and 6.)
8. $(\lnot \beta\to \beta)$ (Deduction theorem, discharging Assumption 3.)
9. $(\lnot \beta\to \beta)\to \beta$ (4)
10. $\beta$ (MP from 8. and 9.)
11. $(\alpha\to \beta)$ (Deduction theorem, discharging Assumption 2.)
12. $(\lnot\beta\to \lnot\alpha)\to (\alpha\to \beta)$ (Deduction theorem, discharging Assumption 1.)